# QuestPDF: Trying to get two spans of text on the same line

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

In the **QuestPDF** library, I'm trying to get text aligned to both left and right side inside the same Item. Basically it will be a lot of properties listed, with the label aligned on the left hand side, and the values aligned on the right hand side.

Basically this is how it looks if I add several `Text` elements, but I want the label and data on the same line, and not on separate lines.

[image]

Comment: Use a 2 column  table and put text in cells. After all what you show is a table

Comment: @KevinBrown - Basically some variant of that I ended up going with. Thanks :)